# Print exact value of PyTorch tensor (floating point precision)

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to print `torch.FloatTensor` like:

```
a = torch.FloatTensor(3,3)
print(a)
```

This way I can get a value like:

```
0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  3.2286e-41
1.2412e-40  1.2313e+00  1.6751e-37
2.6801e-36  3.5873e-41  9.4463e+21
```

But I want to get more accurate value, like 10 decimal point:

```
0.1234567891+01
```

With other python numerical objects, I could get it with:

```
print('{:.10f}'.format(a))
```

but in the case of a tensor, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to torch.FloatTensor.__format__
```

How can I print more precise values of tensors?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can set the precision options:

```
torch.set_printoptions(precision=10)
```

There are more formatting options on the [documentation page](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#creation-ops), it is very similar to numpy's.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a side note, this functionality has been taken from numpy. One of the reasons why PyTorch is smart is because they took many the good ideas from numpy.

However, in numpy the default precision is 8 and in PyTorch the default is 4.

[image]