# PyTorch tensors element differ from numpy arrays after conversion

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I'm working on a metric and i want the numbers to be identically the same, for example:

```
torch.manual_seed(12)
a = torch.tensor(size=(10,1), dtype=torch.double)
b = a.numpy()
```

**a**

```
tensor([[0.8919],
        [0.9859],
        [0.6348],
        [0.8811],
        [0.9391],
        [0.1173],
        [0.1342],
        [0.9405],
        [0.6803],
        [0.5556]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

**b**

```
array([[0.89187783],
       [0.98594254],
       [0.63482434],
       [0.88114518],
       [0.93908453],
       [0.11732954],
       [0.1342178 ],
       [0.94047487],
       [0.68025023],
       [0.55559111]])
```

I want to avoid this difference in the values, how can i do that?

Comment: Pytorch just prints the values at lower precision than numpy by default. The values in memory should not be different. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483819/2790047) to adjust pytorch print precision.

Comment: Yea it does, Thanks!