# values are slightly changed when converting Tensor to Numpy in PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I ran the code below to convert tensor to numpy but values are slightly changed in spite of the same data type.

```
import torch
import numpy

a = torch.load("path to saved tensor")
print("tensor data type: ", a.dtype)
print("first 5 values: ", a[:5])
b = a.numpy()
print("numpy data type: ", b.dtype)
print("first 5 values: ", b[:5])
```

The result is here:

```
tensor data type:  torch.float32
first 5 values:  tensor([-0.5084, -0.2898,  0.0860,  1.3595,  0.5308])
numpy data type:  float32
first 5 values:  [-0.50837755 -0.28977072  0.08596492  1.3595085   0.5307576 ]
```

What happened? And how can I solve this?

version:
pytorch 1.8.1, numpy 1.19.2

Comment: Looks like a display precision difference

Comment: Yes, binary data the same, so that they are equal, just printed differently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print exact value of PyTorch tensor (floating point precision)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483733/print-exact-value-of-pytorch-tensor-floating-point-precision)

Comment: yes! this was a precision difference! thanks a lot!