# Does 1. == 1.0 in numpy and pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, decimal, decimalformat

The output of methods such as

```
a=torch.ones(1,4)
```

is

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Does the number '1.' is the abbreviation of '1.0', or it is exactly the same as integer '1'?

Sorry to ask such a simple question because I don't know which key words are appropriate to search in offical documentation.

Comment: you can do `type(1.)` and `type(1.0)` and you will see that both cases return `<class 'float'>`  Notice that what you do in your title: `1. == 1.0`  is not a good way of checking because  `1 == 1.0` also returns true, although `type(1) != type(1.0)`

Comment: This is really the sort of question you should get in the habit of trying to figure out for yourself. Not because of wasting people's time (if people's time was *that* valuable then they wouldn't be hanging out here), but because in the long term it'll help you gain more familiarity and confidence with the language.

Comment: WRT you not knowing where to look: questions about the basic syntax of the language are best answered by the "Language reference" section of the manual; and things like this -- numbers and strings you write directly in the code to get them into variables -- are known as "literals". Over time you'll pick up widely-used terms like "literal" and "expression" and "statement" and it'll be easier to find stuff.

Comment: The question is not that simple as it might look at first glance. The **representation** of numbers (what you see when printing or converting to a string) in packages like `numpy` or `pytorch` is different from that in Python itself. The number `1.0000000000001` is shown by Python as it is (actually it isn't exactly that number anymore but as near as possible) while the aforementioned packages round the representation by default to `1.`. For details see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483733/print-exact-value-of-pytorch-tensor-floating-point-precision

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, the number '`1.`' is equivalent to '`1.0`', which is a floating-point number.

So, it's not the same as the integer '`1`'. In the tensor you provided, the numbers are represented as floating-point numbers with one decimal point, not integers.